# Why does clustering by hamming distance in MATLAB give centroids in decimal?

Tags: matlab, cluster-computing, hamming-distance

```
    X=[1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1;
       0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0;
       1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1;
       1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0;
       0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0;  
       1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1;
       1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0;
       0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1];

    [IDX,C] = kmeans(X,3, 'distance', 'hamming')
```

I wanted to test how to cluster binary data using hamming distance So in the code above I've randomly allotted X a matrix of binary values. The problem however, is that my centroids are in decimal values. Like I've shown below.

```
C=
    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000         0         0    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
         0    0.5000         0    1.0000    1.0000         0    1.0000    0.5000
    1.0000         0    0.5000         0    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000         0
```

Why is there a 0.5 in the answer? I want the centroids to be binary too. Also is it possible to plot the clusters without the overlap because of binary data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [centroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroids) is an imaginary point (*imaginary* in the sense that it is not necessarily one of the data points), which is the geometric center for the corresponding  data cluster. Think of it as its "center of mass".

Centroids very often fall in between the points in the cluster. Therefore, if your data points are binary, it is expected that the coordinates of the centroids would not be integers.

If you want the centroid coordinates to be binary as well, the simplest solution would involve applying a rounding function such as [round](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html), [ceil](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ceil.html), [floor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/floor.html) or [fix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fix.html).

Comment: Do you know how matlab go about the update step in the case where the Hamming distance is used?

Comment: @Dror I'm not sure what you're asking about. It only determines how the distances in the data space are calculated; if the Hamming distance is used, then the distance is (quote from the [official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.htm): `... the proportion of bits that differ. Each centroid is the component-wise median of points in that cluster.`).

Comment: Right. I missed that somehow. How much sense would it make to snap the centroid to the closets data point? I guess you could do that also when using the Euclidean metric.

Comment: @Dror That's probably your only option if you insist on staying in the binary space. However, when you calculate the "closest" data point, use the same distance function that has been used by `kmeans`.